# Slow Aggregation MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My Aggregation is pretty slow. I've already made it a little faster (from 3000 ms to 200ms) by using the match statement before the unwind statement. Is there any other way to improve my aggregation? In the end there'll be just one result (the last one based on timestamp). The unwind part is the longest operation if i'm right yet i really do need this.

```
db.CpuInfo.aggregate([ 
    {"$match": 
        {
            "timestamp": {"$gte":1464764400},
            'hostname': 'baklap4'
        }
    }, 
    { "$unwind": "$cpuList" }, 
    { "$group": 
        { "_id": 
            { "interval": 
                { "$subtract": [ 
                    "$timestamp",
                    { "$mod": [ "$timestamp", 60 * 5 ] }
                ]}
            }, 
            "avgCPULoad": { "$avg": "$cpuList.load" }, 
            "timestamp": { "$max": "$timestamp" }
        }
    }, 
    { "$project": { "_id": 0, "avgCPULoad": 1, "timestamp": 1 } }, 
    {$sort: {'timestamp': -1}}, 
    {$limit: 1}
])
```

The items in my collection are all simular to this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("574d6175da461e77030041b7"),
  "hostname": "VPS",
  "timestamp": NumberLong(1460040691),
  "cpuCores": NumberLong(2),
  "cpuList": [
    {
      "name": "cpu1",
      "load": 3.4
    },
    {
      "name": "cpu2",
      "load": 0.7
    }
  ]
}
```

I've added the explain option to my aggregation and this is the result:

```
{
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "timestamp" : {
                        "$gte" : 1464732000
                    },
                    "hostname" : "baklap4"
                },
                "fields" : {
                    "cpuList" : 1,
                    "timestamp" : 1,
                    "_id" : 0
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "prototyping.CpuInfo",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "hostname" : {
                                    "$eq" : "baklap4"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "timestamp" : {
                                    "$gte" : 1464732000
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "hostname" : {
                                "$eq" : "baklap4"
                            }
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "timestamp" : NumberLong(1)
                            },
                            "indexName" : "timestamp_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "timestamp" : [
                                    "[1464732000.0, inf.0]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind" : {
                "path" : "$cpuList"
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "interval" : {
                        "$subtract" : [
                            "$timestamp",
                            {
                                "$mod" : [
                                    "$timestamp",
                                    {
                                        "$const" : 300
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "avgCPULoad" : {
                    "$avg" : "$cpuList.load"
                },
                "timestamp" : {
                    "$max" : "$timestamp"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project" : {
                "_id" : false,
                "timestamp" : true,
                "avgCPULoad" : true
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort" : {
                "sortKey" : {
                    "timestamp" : -1
                },
                "limit" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

When i Look up in my table i see that Timestamp and Id are indexed:

```
db.CpuInfo.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "prototyping.CpuInfo"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "timestamp" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        "name" : "timestamp_1",
        "ns" : "prototyping.CpuInfo",
        "sparse" : false
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes created on your collection? I would suggest creating a compound index on the fields `{ "timestamp": 1, "hostname": 1 }` to leverage the query with the `$match` operator. See [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/) and [Pipeline Operators and Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes).

Comment: I have timestamp and hostname indexed yes! I needed that before aggregation already.

Comment: Try to use the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) option in your pipeline to see what's happening with your aggregation operation, which indexes are being used and at what stages.

Comment: I've updated my question. To make a compound index on timestamp and hostname one would run `db.CpuInfo.dropIndex( { "timestamp": 1 } )` and `db.CpuInfo.createIndex({'timestamp': 1, 'hostname': 1})` right?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Hmmm strange i did so and now the time decreased from 200ms to 500ms

Comment: is it possible to calculate/store the interval for each document prior to the aggregate query?

Comment: @CodeMan Why would one calculate and store the interval for each document?
I've already stored timestamp which is currently used to get every document between x seconds. As there is no option to do it without aggregation i had to do this with it.

Comment: I guess it depends on the behaviour of your application. If you are running this aggregation on the same data multiple times, then it may make sense to pre-calculate the interval. Then your aggregate doesn't waste time doing the calculation multiple times. However, if you only ever aggregate the latest records once, then it wouldn't be beneficial to do the pre-calculation.